# Ping sending errors

Tags: .net, winforms, ping

I'm trying to send a ping request to many IP addresses but I always get "General failure".

I.m working in a windows form project and when I try to ping to any address I get an error message -

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingException' occurred in System.dll

Even when I try to send the ping with the CMD it doesn't work.

What can be the solution for that problem?

Comment: "Even when I try to send the ping with the CMD it doesn't work." Doesn't really sound like a programming issue then...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to control your internet connection. This problem mostly happends because of internet connection. If you are connected to the google with your browser then you definitely can ping to somewhere.
Secondly You can reset your modem or restart. I think the problem will be gone.

Comment: Actually, no.  I had a situation today where I could connect to any website, but when I tried to ping something, I got "General Failure".  See my answer below for the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling your Base Filtering engine.  In the Start search box, type "msconfig".  Under services, find "Base Filtering Engine" and uncheck it.  You'll have to reboot to finish the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Do *not* disable your Base Filtering Engine.

Just go to Start -> Administrative Tools -> Windows Firewall, look for "Outbound Rules", then look for "Internet Control Message Protocol", and enable it.  If you can't ping, then you have it disabled.